# render partial with slim-lang grunt-slim plugin throws "undefined method render"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gruntjs, slim-lang

I'm trying to work with slim-lang for my web project. I have the following setup:

- ruby 2.0
- rails 4.0
- node v0.10.17

This setup is working with grunt and the grunt-slim plugin.

At first glance, the slim templates compile all right, but when I try to work with partials, I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `render' for #Object:0x000000029db190
```

Example code to reproduce:

_foo.slim:

`a (href="#") click`

bar.slim:

`= render 'foo'`

I'm a front end developer, so I don't know enough about ruby or rails. I don't understand what causes this error-- is it the grunt-slim plugin or something to do with ruby?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: the only way i got it working was using:

`== Slim::Template.new("app/views/pages/_foo.slim").render`

seems like the long way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the grunt-slim plugin [calls the command-line slim utility](https://github.com/matsumos/grunt-slim/blob/master/tasks/slim.js#L49). I was able to reproduce the error message you're getting by creating the two example files you gave and running:

```
slimrb --trace bar.slim
```

This error is happening because a bare `render` method isn't part of the slim gem, it's part of rails. I was able to get the above command to work by changing `bar.slim` to be:

```
= Slim::Template.new('_foo.slim').render
```

This is clearly more verbose, sorry. I'm not sure if there's a better way to integrate grunt and rails' templates that would get around this issue, but you could just let rails do the rendering.

Comment: it works but renders `&lt;p&gt;header&lt;/p&gt;` instead of tags…

Comment: oh, you forgot to add second `=`.